# Transmitting digital signal long distances, without complex parts

Tags: multiplexer, transmission

I'm controlling several multiplexers from NI DO modules.  The multiplexers channel select inputs, A0-A4, are 5v.  The DO modules output 5v TTL.  On the bench I have everything working exactly the way I want.

Real world application is going to require 500+ feet of transmission distance.  I can't go into specific details, but on the receiving end I can not use 'smart' components due to extreme environment.  The muxes are specially made and only complex part.  The only parts I can use are passive components, RLC, diodes.

Opamps, optocouplers, etc. fail in this environment (Where the muxes are located.  Where the NI equipment is I can use any technology available)

My thoughts are to use FETs, controlled by the DO's, to transmit 48v signals.  Then reduce them with a voltage divider in the harsh environment, to bring it down to 5v to control the muxes.

I'm brainstorming any other ideas, or reasons why this will not work reliably?  Most likely will be switching in the 10-50kHz range.

[image: How I can send the signal (not ttl)]

Comment: 500ft is too much for TTL. Perhaps OK with RS232 serial. Or you can can use ESP8288 WiFi, or 433MHz/2.4GHz RF transceivers. All above are hobbyist stuff.

Comment: RS422, RS423 or RS485 : industrial grade versions of RS232 which won't be up to it.

Comment: Can you locate a repeater or buffer circuit closer than 500 feet but outside the "extreme environment"?

Comment: I can not, the harsh environment is a large area.

Comment: Forget I said TTL as it's not what I'm worried about.  I can send the voltages via the picture I attached the the first post.  I'm more wondering if I should have noise issues sending just 5v to the muxes over that long distance.  Or if I should use something like 48v, then use a 'voltage divider' to bring the 48 down to 5v in the harsh environment.  Or would that even be helpful?

Comment: How electromagnetically noisy is the environment?

Comment: Fiber optics OK?

Comment: No fiber.  Noise is hard to answer, but I would say fairly noisy.

Comment: I say RS485. What data rate do you need?

Comment: What happened when you simply did the obvious thing - sent 5V signals down the 500-foot cable?

Comment: Could be a job for current loops.  Maybe even received by relays, if things are that extreme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a bipolar transistor in emitter follower configuration on each TTL output, to lower the output impedance and boost current capability. Otherwise, I would expect various telecomms line drivers to be available to suit your needs. Presumably you are using signal-return paired connections, as well as an overall 0V line and protective shield/ground.

If the environment is electromagnetically noisy then you might also want to use co-ax or shielded-pair cable to provide individual shielding as well as the line return paths; just make sure there is 100 ohms or so in series in any 0v or ground loop. Some more general EMI filtering might also be appropriate, depending on the nature of the environment.

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to what  was thinking.  Any advantage to raising the transmission voltage from 5v to 48v, then voltage dividing it back down to 5v right before the multiplexer?  

Can you expand on the 100ohms in series?  All the cables will be twisted/shielded.

Comment: The main advantage to the voltage tinkering is improved noise rejection, which will not be significant for a digital signal unless the EMC environment is also harsh. It also has a downside in increased emissions. If you need to compensate for voltage loss, 12V should be more than enough. The 100 ohms is to break current loops between any 0V and ground lines which are connected at both ends - of which there are likely to be quite a few. Otherwise the loops will pick up a lot of mains hum and possibly other rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of info left out but current tends to be more resilient to noise than voltage.
So you could use the TTL to control a constant current source to drive levels of current, say 0mA = logic 0 and 500mA = 1.  Then on the RX side, a 10Ω resistor.

500mA * 10Ω = 5V

Twist the transmission wires fairly tightly together, so that any noise injected into the wires with be equal and thuse rejected fairly well.